How to generate conditions before evaluating integral
The integral
Integrate[E^((a - b) x), x]
should return E^((a-b)x)/(a-b) which should give x when a=b. But Mathematica naively simplifies this to Infinity because of the a-b term. One can show that this term does tend to x using a limit a->b. And if the expression is simplified before integrating, the case when a=b should also result in x.

This may not be what you are looking for Integrate[E^((a-b)x), x,Assumptions->a!=b] and Integrate[E^((a-b)x),x,Assumptions->a==b]

Note that Limit[E^((a - b) x)/(a - b), x -> 0] is 1/(a - b) and Limit[E^((a - b) 1)/(a - b), a -> b, Direction -> "FromAbove"] = \[Infinity] and Limit[E^((a - b) 1)/(a - b), a -> b, Direction -> "FromBelow"] = -\[Infinity]

I do not know a robust way of doing this. Reduce[] can generate conditions, at least in some cases. It can work in this case; see my answer and my comments below.

@CraigCarter how is this consistent with l'hopitals rule? Isnt mathematica just wrong?

Much easier and free from any ambiguity is to start with a definite integral
Integrate[E^((a-b)*t), {t, 0, x}];

Then, if needed we can take a limit:
Limit[%, a -> b]
(* x *)


+1. The same approach works with Integrate[t^n, {t, 1, x}].

This is my preference for Integrate, too (as shown in my answer). But you don't answer the question, how to generate the conditione?

@MichaelE2 right, I do not know how to generate them. I felt,  it's a XY problem.

Ah, I didn't think of that. I did think the limit discussion was a red-herring and not important for the OP. BTW, when one knows there are no branch-cut difficulties, Integrate[..,x] /. {{x -> a}, {x -> x}} // Differences // First can be faster. Integrate is much more careful with definite integrals, and I was hoping that I could get it give an answer with conditions. But I couldn't. (Unless I set the base point to infinity.)

@MichaelE2 This is a good point indeed. Indefinite integration is faster and should be used in a way you show.

Here's a cute way to implement the antiderivative approach in my comment below:
myInt[x_] = <|(* order of keys matters *)
   "conditioner" ->
    (Reduce[\[FormalP] == # && $Assumptions, {x}, Reals] &),
   "solver" -> (Flatten@
       SolveValues[#, {\[FormalP]}, Reals, 
        MaxExtraConditions -> All] &),
   "pwprep" -> (* collect conditions & values *)
    Transpose @* ReplaceAll[
      ConditionalExpression[val_, cond_] :>
      {cond, FullSimplify[val, Simplify@cond]}],
   "toPiecewise" :> (PiecewiseExpand[#, 
        Method -> {"OrderlessConditions" -> True}] &) @*
      (Apply@Internal`ToPiecewise),
   "integrator" -> (Integrate[#, x] &)
   |>;

OP's example:
Fold[myInt[x][#2][#1] &, E^((a - b) x), Keys@myInt[x]]
(*
Piecewise[{{x, a - b == 0}},
 E^((a - b)*x)/(a - b)]
*)

More examples:
Fold[myInt[x][#2][#1] &, Log[1 + ((a - b) x)], Keys@myInt[x]]
(*
Piecewise[{
 {((-a + b)*x + (1 + a*x - b*x)*Log[1 + a*x - b*x])/(a - b), 
   a - b != 0}},
 0]
*)

Fold[myInt[x][#2][#1] &, Cos@((a - b) x), Keys@myInt[x]]
(*  Piecewise[{{x, a - b == 0}}, Sin[(a - b)*x]/(a - b)]  *)

Fold[myInt[x][#2][#1] &, Sin@((a - b) x), Keys@myInt[x]]
(*
Piecewise[{
 {-(Cos[(a - b)*x]/(a - b)),
   Element[C[1], Integers] && 
    a - b != 0 && -(Pi/2) <= a*x - b*x - 2*Pi*C[1] <= (3*Pi)/2}},
 0]
*)

Assuming[-Pi/2 < (a - b) x < Pi/2, (* not perfect *)
 Fold[myInt[x][#2][#1] &, Tan@((a - b) x), Keys@myInt[x]] // 
  FullSimplify
 ]
(*
SolveValues::ztest: Unable to decide whether numeric quantities {-\[Pi]-8 ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]],\[Pi]+8 ArcTan[1-Sqrt[2]]} are equal to zero. Assuming they are.

Piecewise[{{Log[Cos[(a - b)*x]]/(-a + b), a != b && x != 0}}, 0]
*)


First answer
From the ashes of disaster grow the roses of success:
y'[x] == E^((a - b) x) //
       (* FAILS! but NEEDED!! *)
       Reduce[#, {x}, Reals] & //
      (* get integrand(s) with conditions *)
      SolveValues[#, y'[x], Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All] & //
     (* restructure *)
     Flatten //
    (* integrate each *)
    Map[Integrate[#, {x, 0, x}] &] // (* {x,0,x} seemed better *)
   (* restructure for Piecewise[] *)
   ReplaceAll[ConditionalExpression -> List] //
  (* convert to piecewise form *)
  Piecewise[#, Undefined] & //
 (* get rid of unnecessary condition *)
 Simplify[#, {a, b} \[Element] Reals] &


Throw in a // Echo at the end of any line to see the intermediate calculation.


I cannot yet explain why `Solve[Reduce[eqn]]` works but `Solve[eqn]` fails, given that `Reduce[eqn]` returns unevaluated. Mysteries are cool
. 

It seems Solve[] replaces the solve-variable y'[x] with a symbolic representative. If we do so manually -- replace y'[x] by, say, p in both the equation and in SolveVariables[..] -- then the code executes without an error message. I guess Solve[] does not reject equations wrapped in Reduce[] out of hand.

The result $x$ for $a=b$ depends on the initial point of integration (x == 0 in the above). A more general result is $x-c$ if the integral is from $c$ to $x$. Since $x$ was the desired result, I chose $c=0$.

Another route to the piecewise result begins with Reduce[y'[x] == E^((a - b) x), {a, b, y'[x], x}, Reals], which does evaluate. The above came from an attempt to shorten the route. Since something interesting happens in the above, I thought it was more worth publishing.

Integrating with Integrate[#, x, GeneratedParameters -> (Piecewise[{{C[a, b, ##], a == b}}, C[a, b, ##]/(a - b)] &)] & also gives a nice result.

An antiderivative alternative: Integrate[  Internal`ToPiecewise @@ Transpose[Flatten[SolveValues[Reduce[p == E^((a - b) x), {x}, Reals], {p}, Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All]] /. ConditionalExpression[val_, cond_] :> {cond, val}], x]

You must specify the condition in the integral. Consider:
Integrate[E^((a - b) x), x, Assumptions -> a == b]

x

However, if you set a==b after the integral is evaluated:
t = Integrate[E^((a - b) x), x]

E^((a - b) x)/(a - b)

and then simplify t with the assumption a==b:
Simplify[t, a == b]

ComplexInfinity

which is correct, because Limit[Exp[x],x->0]==1
